# Navbar Collapse not working on LoggedInTemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm new in asp and I'm having trouble using `navbar collapse`. It works fine in homepage(AnonymousTemplate), but when I logged in `navbar collapsed` is not working(not expanding when clicked).

Here's is my code. I'm new here so please be gentle. Sorry for the question.

Thanks for anyone who will answer, it will be greatly appreciated.

[In here it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp9ng.png)

[In here it doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqFuR.png)

Here are my script and html.

```js
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```html
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/service/logo.png"></asp:Image></a>
                </div>

               <div runat="server" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
               <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="HowItWorks.aspx" >How it works?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact us</a></li>                        
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About us <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="Secure/Default.aspx">Our Customers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Truckers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                
                    </ul> 
                    </AnonymousTemplate> 
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="CustomerPage.aspx">My profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="AdvancedBooking.aspx" >Advanced Booking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Transaction History</a></li>                        
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About us<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="Secure/Default.aspx">Our Customers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Truckers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><asp:LoginStatus runat="server" /></li>                     
                    </ul>
                   </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
           </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after many tests I finally got my answer. I changed:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add "/" at the start to locate it at the root folder. Sorry if this one is a silly mistake. I only started 1 month in asp.net. I am posting this answer for anyone who will face this issue too.

-RobM

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an unique name to the other dropdown menu and link the other data-toggle to it like this:

```
<AnonymousTemplate>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="HowItWorks.aspx" >How it works?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact us</a></li>                        
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About us <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="Secure/Default.aspx">Our Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Truckers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                
                </ul> 
                </AnonymousTemplate> 
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="CustomerPage.aspx">My profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="AdvancedBooking.aspx" >Advanced Booking</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Transaction History</a></li>                        
                    <li class="dropdown2">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown2">About us<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="Secure/Default.aspx">Our Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Truckers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><asp:LoginStatus runat="server" /></li>                     
                </ul>
               </LoggedInTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks, the dropdown works fine. The navbar, when in collapse I cant expand it to view the options. I cant see my "My Profile", "Advanced Booking" etc, etc.

Comment: after a few test, it seems like my collapse navbar only works in root directory, not inside another folder. i mean it collapsed but not expanding, any idea ?